# Adding Grand Totals in Pivot Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, dynamic-sql

I have created a pivot table with the following code:

```
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Columns AS VARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @Columns =
COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','')+ QUOTENAME(PortfolioID)
FROM
(
SELECT PortfolioID FROM InfoPortal.DBO.fn_Generic_PortfolioGroupMembers (@PortfolioGroup)
) AS B
ORDER BY B.PortfolioID

SET @SQL = '
WITH PivotData AS
(
    SELECT 
        PortfolioID, Percentage, DurationBand, DurationSort 
    FROM #Worktable
)

SELECT 
    DurationBand, 
    ' + @Columns + '
FROM PivotData
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Percentage)
    FOR PortfolioID
    IN (' + @Columns + ')
) AS PivotResult
ORDER BY DurationSort'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

However what i would like to do is add grand totals for each portfolioID, and i'm unsure of how to achieve this.  Any help?

Comment: Do you want the grand total as an additional row or as a column?

Comment: i would like a grand total row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add a `GROUP BY with ROLLUP` to produce the totals row, similar to this:

```
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Columns AS VARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnsRollup AS VARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @Columns =
COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','')+ QUOTENAME(PortfolioID)
FROM
(
    SELECT distinct PortfolioID 
    FROM worktable
) AS B
ORDER BY B.PortfolioID

SELECT @ColumnsRollup =
COALESCE(@ColumnsRollup + ', Sum(','Sum(')+ QUOTENAME(cast(PortfolioID as varchar(10)))+') as Portfolio'+cast(PortfolioID as varchar(10))
FROM
(
    SELECT distinct PortfolioID 
    FROM worktable
) AS B
ORDER BY B.PortfolioID

SET @SQL = '
            WITH PivotData AS
            (
                SELECT PortfolioID, Percentage, DurationBand, DurationSort 
                FROM Worktable
            )
            SELECT case when DurationBand is not null then cast(durationband as varchar(10))
                else ''Total'' end Durationband, ' + @ColumnsRollup+ '
            FROM
            (
                SELECT DurationBand, ' + @Columns + '
                FROM PivotData
                PIVOT
                (
                    SUM(Percentage)
                    FOR PortfolioID IN (' + @Columns + ')
                ) AS PivotResult
            ) src
            GROUP BY DurationBand with ROLLUP'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bba34/18).  *Note: sample data is just mocked based on your table structure.*

Result:

```
| DURATIONBAND | PORTFOLIO1 | PORTFOLIO2 | PORTFOLIO3 |
-------------------------------------------------------
|            2 |         78 |     (null) |     (null) |
|            5 |     (null) |     (null) |          4 |
|           12 |         10 |         45 |     (null) |
|        Total |         88 |         45 |          4 |
```

Based in the need to keep things sorted, you can use:

```
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Columns AS VARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnsRollup AS VARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @Columns =
COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','')+ QUOTENAME(PortfolioID)
FROM
(
    SELECT distinct PortfolioID 
    FROM worktable
) AS B
ORDER BY B.PortfolioID

SELECT @ColumnsRollup =
COALESCE(@ColumnsRollup + ', Sum(','Sum(')+ QUOTENAME(cast(PortfolioID as varchar(10)))+') as '+QUOTENAME(cast(PortfolioID as varchar(10)))
FROM
(
    SELECT distinct PortfolioID 
    FROM worktable
) AS B
ORDER BY B.PortfolioID

SET @SQL = '
            WITH PivotData AS
            (
                SELECT PortfolioID, Percentage, DurationBand, DurationSort 
                FROM Worktable
            )
            SELECT *
            FROM
            (
                SELECT DurationBand, ' + @Columns + '
                FROM PivotData
                PIVOT
                (
                    SUM(Percentage)
                    FOR PortfolioID IN (' + @Columns + ')
                ) AS PivotResult
                UNION ALL
                select ''Grand Total'', '+@ColumnsRollup+'
                from
                (
                    SELECT DurationBand, ' + @Columns + '
                    FROM PivotData
                    PIVOT
                    (
                        SUM(Percentage)
                        FOR PortfolioID IN (' + @Columns + ')
                    ) AS PivotResult
                )tot
            ) src
            '

EXEC (@SQL)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d9cb/2)

Comment: Looks good, a couple of things though.  How can i make "Grand Total" appear in Duration Band column?  How can i order the pivot by DurationSort but keep the total at the bottom?

Comment: @chrissyp I updated the code to remove the null and replace it with `total` in the `durationband` column.  I am not sure what you mean order the `pivot` by `durationsort`, can you alter the sql fiddle with some sample data and then explain the desired result?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @bluefeet however i still can get it to sort by DurationSort.  It must be as simple as adding ORDER BY DurationSort in somewhere?  Basically duration sort is just an INT running from 1,2,3...... so that i can sort the duration band stings into the correct order.  I think i've updated SQL Fiddle correctly.

Comment: @chrissyp can you provide the link for the sql fiddle?

Comment: probably a rubbish example:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/959fa/1

Basically i want the DurationBand to go in the correct order, so i created DurationSort to force it

Comment: @chrissyp if you want to remove the portfolio, then you can use the following code in this fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bba34/36.  I have not been able to reproduce this getting the result out of order to try and then order them, but I am still trying.

Comment: this is a better example @bluefeet: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d9cb/1  can you see that 10-19.99 is in the wrong place so i would need to sort it by Duration Sort to ensure that this came last before the total?

Comment: @chrissyp see this demo and let me know if if works with your full dataset -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d9cb/2

Comment: Works perfectly @bluefeet, do you edit your answer above or do i?