# Displaying products sales for each day in SQL

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have a problem I can't find a solution.

I have a table "SELLS" with all sells of a shop and I want to display how many sales for each product each day of a period.

For example :

```
|       DATE |  NAME    | QTY |
|------------|----------|-----|
| 2014-07-03 |     Coca |   1 |
| 2014-07-03 |    Fanta |   1 |
| 2014-07-03 | Orangina |   5 |
| 2014-07-03 |     Coca |   3 |
| 2014-07-04 |     Coca |   2 |
| 2014-07-05 |     Coca |   4 |
| 2014-07-05 |    Fanta |   1 |
| 2014-07-05 |    Juice |   2 |
```

The display i want is :

```
    |       NAME | TOTAL  | 2014-07-03 |  2014-07-04 |  2014-07-05 |
    |------------|--------|------------|-------------|-------------|
    |      Coca  |   10   |         4  |          2  |          4  |
    |     Fanta  |    2   |         1  |          0  |          1  |
    |  Orangina  |    1   |         1  |          0  |          0  |
    |     Juice  |    1   |         0  |          0  |          1  |
```

The user will specify the period he wants to display, so I have to use a BETWEEN function for date.

I try with PIVOT function, but I'm still not familiar using it

Edit : I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What RDBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc) are you using?

Comment: And can you show what you've tried?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server, I edit my question.
@Politank-Z what I try display an error so not very useful I think ... On a previous question, the solution was PIVOT but it was for Sums of sales per payments methods

Comment: does this help..  http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Comment: Showing what you've already tried, even if it doesn't work, can help the person answering your question to more precisely understand what you are trying to do, and if you aren't completely wrong, offer a more precise answer.

Comment: Similar like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: A better example that will also give you a row total and the dynamic generation of the date column names http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081086/t-sql-pivot-total-row-and-dynamic-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create table temp 
(
tdate date,
name varchar(10),
qty int
)

insert into temp values (getdate(),'A',10)

insert into temp values (getdate(),'B',20)

insert into temp values (getdate(),'C',20)
insert into temp values (getdate(),'A',20)
insert into temp values (getdate(),'B',30)
insert into temp values (getdate(),'C',40)
insert into temp values (getdate()+1,'A',20)
insert into temp values (getdate()+1,'B',30)
insert into temp values (getdate()+1,'C',40)




select * from 
( select tdate, name, qty
  from temp
) src
pivot (
  sum(qty)
  for tdate in ([2015-05-12],[2015-05-13])
) piv;
```

Comment: `select convert(CHAR(10), [tdate], 120) as tdate, name, qty ...` for sanity purposes.

Comment: i have an error because [2015-05-12] is a varchar and i'm using datetime. It seems cast don't work in that case ? or am I wrong again ?

Comment: I tried changing *tdate* column datatype to *datetime* and it still worked. Could you please share your table definition?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TICKET_VENTE](
 [DATE] [datetime] NULL,
 [LIBELLE] [varchar](40) NULL,
 [QTE] [float] NULL)`

Comment: Well first thing first, why do you have a column with *[Date]* a keyword? and probably the error is in the date format. What is your date format that you have in your table? (DDMMYYYY/ MMDDYYYY/ YYYYMMDD etc)

Comment: The table is create automatically by an other software, I can't change that.
Here is an example of a value : 2015-03-16 00:00:00.000 (YYYY-MM-DD)

Comment: hunh... what is the error man.. I guess it should work.. It worked for me... u just copy paste the above code and run it.. it will work

Comment: i change the date and it works ... i think it's because 2015-05-13 not appears in my table.
It works fine, thanks for your time and your help !

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't this do the trick?

```
SELECT sum(QTY), DATE, NAME FROM SELLS WHERE DATE BETWEEN .... GROUP BY DATE,NAME
```

P.S: added the between clause